# SQL with nested CASE and joining strings gives trailing spaces

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I am using Firebird 2.5. When I run

```
SELECT 
CASE BILANCA 
  WHEN 1 THEN
    CASE BILANCA WHEN 0 THEN 'SMALLINT' WHEN 1 THEN 'NUME' END
  ELSE 'A'||'B' END
  AS BILANCA1,
  CASE BILANCA 
  WHEN 1 THEN
    CASE BILANCA WHEN 0 THEN 'SMALLINT' WHEN 1 THEN 'NUME' END
  ELSE 'AB' END
  AS BILANCA2
FROM GS01BILANCA
```

field BILANCA2 is `'NUME    '` (there are 4 spaces after NUME) and BILANCA1 is `'NUME'`. Number of added spaces is equal to length of longest string in CASE. 
The only difference is in joining string in BILANCA1:

```
ELSE 'A'||'B' END
```

DDL is

```
CREATE TABLE GS01BILANCA
(BILANCA INTEGER DEFAULT  0 NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_GS01BILANCA PRIMARY KEY (BILANCA));
```

Table has 2 records:

- 1
- 2

Result is

- `'NUME    '` (there are 4 spaces after NUME), `'NUME'`
- `'AB'`, `'AB'`

Question: Is this expected and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String literals in Firebird are of type `CHAR`, the datatype of a case expression will have the longest length of all branches. So with

```
CASE BILANCA WHEN 0 THEN 'SMALLINT' WHEN 1 THEN 'NUME' END
```

The datatype will be `CHAR(8)`. A `CHAR` value will always be right-padded with the spaces to the declared length.

However when one of the branches of a case expression is a `VARCHAR`, then all branches are coerced to a `VARCHAR`. And concatenation in Firebird will always produce a `VARCHAR`, even if both operands are `CHAR`

This means that in the case of `BILANCA1`:

```
CASE BILANCA 
WHEN 1 THEN
    CASE BILANCA WHEN 0 THEN 'SMALLINT' WHEN 1 THEN 'NUME' END
ELSE 'A'||'B' END
```

that `'A'||'B'` is a `VARCHAR(2)`, this causes the entire case to be coerced to `VARCHAR`, which then causes `'SMALLINT'` to become a `VARCHAR(8)` and `'NUME'` a `VARCHAR(4)`, which makes the entire expression becomes a `VARCHAR(8)`.

Note that this type coercion is pushed down, so the literal will be a `varchar` from the start and not be blanked padded* by intermediate evaluation of the innermost case statement.

That is not the case for `BILANCA2`, as all (nested) branches are literals, therefor it will be a `CHAR(8)`.

If you want both to behave the same you can do:

1. Cast the entire expression to the desired type (this would work both for `bilanca1` and `bilanca2`)
2. Cast part of the expression (eg one of the literals or the nested case) to a `varchar`; this only works to force `bilanca2` to a `varchar`
3. Cast the string concatenation to `char`; this only works to force `bilanca1` to a `char`
4. Concatenate an empty string to one of the literals; this only works to force `bilanca2` to a `varchar`
5. Use `trim` on the entire expression (this also coerces to `varchar`)

---

*) This in contrast to for example `cast(cast('nume' as char(8)) as varchar(8))` which will produce `'nume    '` and not just `'nume'` as in this case the intermediate result is preserved, and existing spaces are not thrown away in a `varchar`.